# Entity Framework does not fetch the rows that have a relationship

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have these 2 tables in a SQL Server:

Table #1 `Order`:

```
OrderID    
Name
IsFetched
```

Table #2 `OrderRows`:

```
OrderRowId    
OrderID    
Name
Adress
```

These tables have a relationship on the `OrderID` column: one order can have multiple `OrderRows` that are connected to the `Order` table by the `OrderID` key.

However, when I query the database using Entity Framework 6, I don't get the `OrderRows` that belong to the `Order`, they are always null, why is that? Aren't the `OrderRows` supposed to automatically be populated?

```
    using (var db = new MyDbEntities())
    {
        db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

        try
        {
            var list = db.Order.Where(x => x.IsFetched == null || x.IsFetched == false).ToList();
            return list;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to Include the related entities by adding `.Include(x => x.OrderRows)`

```
   using (var db = new MyDbEntities())
    {
        db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        try
        {
            var list = 
                 db.Order
                  .Include(x => x.OrderRows)
                  .Where(x => x.IsFetched == null || x.IsFetched == false)
                  .ToList();
            return list;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```